# Customize Awkward jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a small customization of the awkward image gallery plugin. The plugin offers image caption. The image caption gets its own div with the class="showcase-caption". Its is based inside the div with the class="showcase-slide".

However the caption is an overlay. I need it to be placed underneath the image. Here is an example page that is pseudo working http://www.awkward.interfacecreation.com/jquery/. In the example the caption just overlays the image though.

Comment: When you say overlay, do you mean the text itself on top of the image, or the containing element? (Note, in FF, IE and Chrome, the caption for each appears to be underneath the image...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.showcase-content {
background-color: black;
text-align: center;
overflow: visible !important;
}
```

style.css line:125

```
.showcase-content-container {
background-color: black;
overflow: visible !important;
}
```

style.css line:87

```
.showcase-caption {
color: black;
padding: 8px 15px;
text-align: left;
position: absolute;
/*bottom: 0px;*/
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
background: #DFDFDF;
margin-top: -5px;
}
```

style.css line:163

Answer (score 0):

The .showcase-caption div is absolutely positioned within #showcase, automatically aligning to the bottom. You need to make #showcase taller and remove the `position: absolute` rule from .showcase-caption in the stylesheet (along with `top` and `left`) so that .showcase-caption can sit beneath .showcase-content.